# How to backup a google sheet script?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to know how we can backup the code (script) automatically or manually in a google sheet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Manually: write on your own computer, then copy-paste to google sheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Apps Script to manage your scripts.

Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard#:%7E:text=To%20access%20this%20toggle%20click,default%20as%20a%20security%20precaution.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Clasp

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp

It is a way to write code from your local computer and then "sync" it from the command line.

To send updates:

```
clasp push
```

To get updates:

```
clasp pull
```

You can then use any version control software like Git on the project because you have it locally as well as on Google's servers. Just remember to sync often!